# How to upload and download any file in the browser?

Tags: javascript, webapi

This is part of an experiment I am working on.

Let's say I upload a file eg: .psd (photoshop file) or .sketch (sketch) through the input type file tag, it displays the name of the file and can be downloaded as a .psd / .sketch on click of a button (without data corruption)

How would this be achieved?

Edit 1:

I'm going to add a bit more info as the above was not completely clear.

This is the flow:

1. User uploads any file
2. File gets encrypted in the client before sending to a sockets.io server
3. User on the other end receives this file and is able to decrypt and download.

Note: There is not database connected with the sockets.io. It just listens and responds to whoever connected to the server.

I got the enc/dec part covered. Only thing is uploading and store as ? in a variable so it can be encrypted and doing the opposite on the recepient end (dec and downlodable)

Thanks again in advance :)

Comment: What's wrong with `<a href="file.psd">file.psd</a>`?

Comment: Add the `download` attribute to the `a` tag

Comment: @Brad I was thinking more along the lines of uploading a file through an input tag and store as base64 (or other) in a variable and download it again?

Comment: Uploading the file where?  And, why would you use base64?

Comment: @Brad I have updated the question, please check it out

Comment: Have a look at: [javascript file encryption](https://tutorialzine.com/2013/11/javascript-file-encrypter) though it does look several years old.

Comment: So, you want to use Socket.IO for this?  If you have control over the server-side connection, why not do it over HTTP instead?  That way, you get transport compression, the browsers handle all the buffering, you don't have to load the whole file into memory, etc. etc. etc.  One side can do a simple HTTP PUT, while the other can do HTTP GET.  The file can stream right through your server.  Also, this way you could just use HTTPS...

Comment: @Brad Not exactly, its part of a chat application. So giving the user an option to upload files (smaller than 3mb). This chat app uses public key enc so want to enc in the client side itself before moving it to the server

Comment: @ATD Thank you but its not about the encryption. The enc/dec system is already in place. Issue is with uploading the file so it can be enc in the client side and then the same for the recepient (dec the same and download).

Comment: @rohanharikr What is your question?  You say to me that it's not about the transport, it's about encryption.  And then you reply to ATD that it's not about the encryption, it's about the transport.  Which is it?  And, I ask you again, why can't you use HTTP for this?

Comment: Wait. What's the issue in uploading the encrypted file?

Comment: @Brad Sorry maybe I was not clear and I should not have brought in all the encryption confusion in this. This is my situation. I am new to backend, so really not sure how I can implement this or ask the question properly. Right now, I want to send the file uploaded in an object as base64 so the receiving end can decode it back to the original file. I'm afraid I cannot be more clearer than this because I am not very technically proficient. Sorry for that.

Comment: @rohanharikr Why do you want to use base64?

Comment: @Brad Because the encryption library (TweetNacl) I am using now requires data to be passed in as Uint8Array and I found a couple of libraries online which can convert base64 to Uint8Array.

Comment: @rohanharikr Why wouldn't you just use a UInt8Array in the first place?  You can read the Blob directly.  All these extra conversions are really inefficient.

Comment: @Brad oh okay got it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think these are your questions:

- How to read a file that was opened/dropped into a `<file>` element
- How to send a file to a server
- How to receive a file from a server

When a user opens a file on your file element, you'll be able to use its [files](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file#files) property:

```
for (const file of fileInputEl.files) {
  // Do something with file here...
}
```

Each file implements the [Blob interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob), which means you can call [`await file.arrayBuffer()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/arrayBuffer) to get an [ArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer), which you can likely use directly in your other library.  At a minimum, you can create your byte array from it.

Now, to send data, I strongly recommend that you use HTTP rather than Socket.IO.  If you're only sending data one way, there is no need for a Web Socket connection or Socket.IO.  If you make a normal HTTP request, you offload all the handling of it to the browser.  On the upload end, it can be as simple as:

```
fetch('https://files.example.com/some-id-here', {
  method: 'PUT'
  body: file
});
```

On the receive end, you can simply open a link `<a href="https://files.example.com/some-id-here">`.

Now, the server part... You say that you want to just pass this file through.  You didn't specify at all what you're doing on the server.  So, speaking abstractly, when you receive a request for a file, you can just wait and not reply with data until the sending end connects and start uploading.  When the sending end sends data, send that data immediately to the receiving end.  In fact, you can pipe the request from the sending end to the response on the receiving end.

You'll probably have some initial signalling to choose an ID, so that both ends know where to send/receive from.  You can handle this via your usual methods in your chat protocol.

Some other things to consider... WebRTC.  There are several [off-the-shelf tools](https://github.com/webtorrent/instant.io) for doing this already, where the data can be sent peer-to-peer, saving you some bandwidth.  There are some complexities with this, but it might be useful to you.